# Conda replaces git url with package name in yml file after conda export

Tags: python, git, pip, conda, environment

I have created a conda environment using a manually made environment.yml file. In that file I have added (under the 'pip' tag) a github repo containing a repo that I need for my project. A snippet of the file looks like this:

```
- pip:
   - git+https://github.com/microsoft/recommenders
```

Which basically means that, when I create a new environment, pip will use the 'pip install git+https://github.com/microsoft/recommenders' command.

However I have now added some new packages and would like to update my environment.yml with these new packages, so I call `conda env export > environment.yml`.

The thing is, when I run this command, suddenly in my environment.yml file, the git+ line is gone and replaced with `reco-utils==2019.9`, so when I call `conda install -f environment.yml` Conda returns an error since it can't find the reco-utils package because it's not a git url anymore.

Is there a way for Conda to keep the git url so that I can export my project dependencies without having to manually add the git dependency again?

Comment: Yeah, it's [an open issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9308). Be sure to add your case to the Issue so it gets more attention. Note, you can at least use `pip freeze` to find those source packages and add them back to the YAML manually.